# download Ubuntu for Vmware

Tags: vmware

I am willing to download Ubuntu for VMware..I'm much confused among Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu desktop,which one should i go for? and what is the differnce between them?

Comment: which one is better among them for installing in VMware

Comment: you can install any one as your choice both will works.But ubuntu server not preloded with GUI desktop.So my recommendation for you is Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

There's one version of the Ubuntu Server, and it does not include any GUI, so if you're comfortable with the Linux CLI (Command Line Interface), it will run faster, and gove you the opportunity to add many services during installation.

You can also use official versions of Ubuntu, described at [Wikipedia's Ubuntu page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Official_distributions) with a GUI: Edubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu (Unity) and Ubuntu GNOME. These and other versions are linked from the [Ubuntu official releases page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).  Although these will not prompt you for services during installation, you can add them later through [apt-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool), the Synaptic Package Manager or the Ubuntu Software Center.